# removefromsuperview doesn't release memory

Tags: memory

I am confused why when i call removeFromSuperview memory which was allocated for removed view doesn't released. so here is part of my code and test results.
I have uiscrollview and uiview which is added on uiscrollview.  so when I scroll my uiscrollview i call removefromsuperview and expect that memory will be released.

```
-(void) someFunction {
 magazineContentView = [[MagazineContentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35 + 320 *i ,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[_scrollView addSubview:magazineContentView];
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
[magazineContentView removeFromSuperview];
magazineContentView = nil;
}
```

magazineContentView removed correctly but memory do not reduced.

I'm not using ARC.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Where are you checking that the memory was not reduced? Instruments? Please include all relevant details in your question.

Comment: thanks for replay, 
no i dont use ARC. i am using standard xcode memory report. I attach screens, as you can see memory size before allocating and adding uiview is 8.5 mb after adding thins view it becomes 9MB but after remove this view from uiscrollview it still stay 9MB!! oops sorry i can not attach screens at this moment I have not permission.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate magazineContentView, and add it as a subview, it gets retained twice. Since you're using Manual Retain Release, and not using ARC, you need to release it at some point after adding it as a subview.

`[magazineContentView removeFromSuperview]` will only bring down the retain count by 1. There's still one retained instance due to the init call.

(FYI You really should not mind / think about retain counts but I'm mentioning it here to explain my answer better).

Also, directly setting your ivar to nil like you're doing won't really help since it's not a property.

You should also not be removing from superview in the didEndDecelerating call. This is bad practice. You've set it to nil, so calling `removeFromSuperview` won't harm anything, but it's not good code design.

Why not just use ARC? It's much cleaner to use.

**If you do insist on using MRR, you should call release on magazineContentView after adding it as a subview. This way, when you call removeFromSuperview on it later, the retains and releases balance out.**

```
-(void) someFunction {
 magazineContentView = [[MagazineContentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35 + 320 *i ,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[_scrollView addSubview:magazineContentView];
[magazineContentView release];
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
// Move these to some other place... e.g. a separate method that does this only once
[magazineContentView removeFromSuperview];
magazineContentView = nil;
}
```

Also, you should be paying closer attention to leaks first, then you should look at the allocation measurement.

Did you have a look at the Memory Management Guidelines by Apple? It's a worthy investment of your time to read through this document and understand MRR a little better -https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html